# Tabs with custom view is not inflating in TabLayout at bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a layout as following -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:id="@+id/main_global_container"
    >


    <!--<include-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/mainAppBar"-->
        <!--layout="@layout/view_appbar" />-->

    <!--<ProgressBar-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="35dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/homescreenProgressbar"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
        <!--android:visibility="invisible"-->
        <!--/>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/upper_container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:background="@color/formInactiveFont"
            android:id="@+id/upper_left_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                <TextView
                    android:text="Welcome,"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Devansh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Custome message will appear here"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    custom:srcCompat="@drawable/hexagone"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                <TextView
                    android:text="100"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/hexagone"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Total Score"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Begainner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:background="@color/accentColor"
            android:id="@+id/upper_right_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:text="Keep Learning"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    custom:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Take Quiz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView13"
                    style="@style/quizBtnHome"
                    android:id="@+id/button4" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/home_view_pager">


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"

         />





</LinearLayout>
```

i am inflating tabs in tablayout with following xml layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
     />

<TextView
    android:text="Topic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_margin="7dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then i am setting up viewpager with my tablayout .

The problem is that i am getting an empty tab layout with empty tabs , they not showing their layout but if i exclude view pager then they are getting inflated properly and show what they are supposed to show .

Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your layout code

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid done

Answer (score 0):

Try this it was happening due to LinearLayout weight i have made changes to set TabLayout bottom and LinearLayout Above Tab Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_global_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabLayout">


        <!--<include-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/mainAppBar"-->
        <!--layout="@layout/view_appbar" />-->

        <!--<ProgressBar-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="35dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/homescreenProgressbar"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
        <!--android:visibility="invisible"-->
        <!--/>-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/upper_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/upper_left_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@color/formInactiveFont"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                        android:text="Welcome,"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                        android:text="Devansh"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
                        android:text="Custome message will appear here"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        custom:srcCompat="@drawable/hexagone"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:background="@color/black"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/hexagone"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="100"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:text="Total Score"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Begainner"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/upper_right_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.3"
                android:background="@color/accentColor"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="Keep Learning"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        custom:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        style="@style/quizBtnHome"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView13"
                        android:text="Take Quiz"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"

            />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem . Btw can you please point out the changes you made?

Comment: I have aligned Tab to bottom and LinearLayout Above Tab Layout

Comment: the problem is somehow related to viewpager because if i exclude it , problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it , so to anyone who might have this problem in future ,

Remove getPageTitle() method from your PagerAdaptor class and do things in this order -

1. add fragments to pageradaptor.
2. setup pageradaptor with you tabslayout
3. inflate tabs with custom layout